# When to use thread local memory in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am just starting with Python and stumbled upon the thread local memory. I wrote a small program that uses threads:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import signal
import threading
import time

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, idx):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_index = idx
        self.thread_alive = True

    def run(self):
        logging.info(f'Thread {self.thread_index} is starting up!')

        while self.thread_alive:
            logging.info(f'Thread {self.thread_index} is still running.')
            time.sleep(1)

        logging.info(f'Thread {self.thread_index} is stopping!')

    def kill(self):
        self.thread_alive = False

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(format = '%(levelname)s: %(message)s', level = logging.INFO)

    def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        logging.info('Ctrl+c pressed, killing threads and shutting down ...')
        nonlocal threads
        for thread in threads:
            thread.kill()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    logging.info('Signal handler registered, starting threads ...')

    threads = []
    for i in range(0, 3):
        thread = WorkerThread(i)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This program works as expected and prints something like:

```sh
> python3 main.py
INFO: Signal handler registered, starting threads ...
INFO: Thread 0 is starting up!
INFO: Thread 0 is still running.
INFO: Thread 1 is starting up!
INFO: Thread 2 is starting up!
INFO: Thread 1 is still running.
INFO: Thread 2 is still running.
INFO: Thread 0 is still running.
INFO: Thread 1 is still running.
INFO: Thread 2 is still running.
INFO: Thread 0 is still running.
INFO: Thread 2 is still running.
INFO: Thread 1 is still running.
INFO: Thread 2 is still running.
INFO: Thread 1 is still running.
INFO: Thread 0 is still running.
INFO: Thread 1 is still running.
INFO: Thread 2 is still running.
INFO: Thread 0 is still running.
^CINFO: Ctrl+c pressed, killing threads and shutting down ...
INFO: Thread 2 is stopping!
INFO: Thread 1 is stopping!
INFO: Thread 0 is stopping!
```

In this case the `thread_index` and `thread_alive` variables are specific for each thread as they are specific for each object. But there is also the `threading.local()` function that creates [thread local memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data). So I tried to use this, as I want my variables to be thread specific. I used it after I defined the class:

```py
# imports and shebang

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    thread_index = threading.local()
    thread_alive = threading.local()

# everything else stays the same
```

But using this does not change anything, the output stays the same. So my questions are:

- is this thread local memory for another use case or did the first program only work by accident?
- what are use cases for `threading.local()`, as creating object specific (non static) variables seem to work too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`threading.local()` is for cases when you cannot or don't want to modify classes that implement threads.

In the above example you are in full control as you've created `WorkerThread` and you have started threads. So you know that you have an instance per running thread and you can store values in the instance that is bound to a thread. That's why your initial example worked. It works correctly in this regard.

But it is not always the case that you control threads. Sometimes threads are started by the library or framework and you only provide some code that will be run in these threads.  In that case you cannot modify `Thread` classes and add thread specific variables to them.

Let's take an example of a multithreaded web server. You provide functions that are supposed to process incoming requests. You do not create all the infrastructure to listen on the socket, parse http request etc. All these activities are handled by the framework. It starts a pool of threads for you and when there's incoming request the framework parses it and invokes the handler you've provided using a thread from the pool.

In this case let's imagine you want to store some context for the request that is being processed (for example the currently logged in user) so that you can access it during request processing but do not need to pass it around in every function explicitly. You can't add this `currentUser` variable to a thread class as you don't have control over it. But you can use `threading.local()` to store it. And requests that are concurrently processed in multiple threads will have their own copies of that.

The same is applicable for your own creations. When the program becomes more complex and you need to separate infrastructure code (managing threads) from the logic of your application it may happen that you do not want to add a thread specific variables to thread classes and use `threading.local()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion: I would never use thread-local storage in new code.

IMO, the best use for thread local storage is when you have an old module that is thread-unaware, and it uses global variables, and you want to be able to call the old module from multiple threads in some new program. In that case, simply replacing all of the globals in the old module with thread-locals can be a cheap way to let each thread in the new program to effectively have its own "copy" of the module.

But, If I was writing a *new* module, to be used in a multi-threaded environment, then there would be no global variables in the module.  All of that state would be *member variables* of some class (or classes,) and the calling threads could each create their own instance(s) of the class(es).

Comment: What if you were writing a common superclass and you need coordinating variables between all of the derived classes? If you don't want your derived classes to know the inner workings of the superclass, how would you implement thread-safe variables that coordinate the derived classes in a concerted fashion? I would love to avoid using `threading.local()` but I also want to obfuscate the superclass and I can't think of a way to do that without mutable class attributes (which are essentially global variables).

Comment: @hepcat72, I don't understand, "coordinating variables between...derived classes." If you're talking about _global_ variables, then I would seek a way to solve the problem without them. And, if you're not talking about global variables, then I'm pretty sure I could solve the problem without using `threading.local` either.

Comment: I'm essentially talking about global variables (technically class attributes, but same issue), and seeking a way to solve the problem with out them is the point of my question. I don't know how to solve it without them. That's what I'm asking you. Regarding what I mean by "coordinating variables between derived classes", it's a deep topic, best discussed outside of this comment section, and I would love a suggested solution that frees me of the global variable pitfalls. Please see this django forum thread: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/threading-local-questions/23496/7